# Function not showing up in OnClick() for unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been trying to get a function to return a number to change the text in a button. However, I can not use the functions I wrote with OnClick(). I won't show up.

Here is the script I've been working with.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class DiceRollerBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int setRandom;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        setRandom = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    public int roll()
    {
        setRandom = Random.Range(1, 10);
        Debug.Log("Your new number is:" + setRandom.ToString());
        return setRandom;
    }



   
}
```

The OnClick() should put the roll function in this list but doesn't.

[image]

I just need to be able to trigger a function in this script using the OnClick() feature for unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to set a callback here it must be `public void`, not `public int`.

Also, your code will not change any text. To be able to do this, you need to assign the text label you want to change to a class field. So, it will look like this:

```
public class DiceRollerBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] 
    private Text _text; // assign this field in the inspector

    public int setRandom;

    void Start()
    {
        setRandom = 0;
    }

    public void OnBtnClick()
    {
        int rollValue = roll();
        _text.text = @"{rollValue}";
    }

    int roll()
    {
        setRandom = Random.Range(1, 10);
        Debug.Log("Your new number is:" + setRandom.ToString());
        return setRandom;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was settling for a debug response. I tried out the change you suggested and it worked perfectly, thanks.